# how to pass data from activity to webview with external website

Tags: java, android, webview

I am making an app for tracking courier. the user will enter tracking no.in apps textview and click submit this will open couriers website tracking page i.e fedex in a webview inside the App.

Now i want a way to pass those tracking no from my app to webview's **website input field** and click the **submit button** on the website automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this the way you should do that, you should look for a url that takes the tracking location number as a query and return the proper page

something like that `http://example.com/over/there?number=441222`

**Update**

I've looked at the page you've mentioned in the comments and all I can get is that it submits a post request as a form input

`POST` url: https://www.myutiitsl.com/PAN_ONLINE/PANTrackerSearch.action
parameter names are
`appNo`
`panNo`

I wish I had more knowledge as a web developer but this the way that could work with you try to make sure the post url is correct and the parameters I mentioned also correct and it should work with you

Comment: But the website don't use such url quering in my case

Comment: Could you provide us with the page url? , I want to check something

Comment: Have a look at these links https://square.github.io/retrofit/ , https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776213/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-retrofit-2

Comment: the website does not have api....i searched and got some lght upon.. it can be done via javascript but how i cant figureout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906557/calling-javascript-method-from-within-webview-in-android

Comment: Thnx i took stuffs from all the links to make it works .. . finally