# Android call Javascript from Java not working

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I've read many posts but I can't get my Android app call a Javascript function. This is what I have

```
public class BorrameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static BorrameActivity.MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface;
    private static WebView webView;

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void doEchoTest(String echo){
            Log.e("printer", echo);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, echo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_borrame);

        myJavaScriptInterface = new BorrameActivity.MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowserAuthorise);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "JSInterface");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loginProtocol.html");
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:JSInterface.doEchoTest('test')"); // THIS WORKS!!
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho()"); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

This works when I execute

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:JSInterface.doEchoTest('test')");
```

But it doesn't work when the Javascript function is in loginProtocol.html:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho()");
```

Where

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="visibility:visible">
    <!--    Used for debugging -->
    <h1>HELLO</h1>

    <script>
        function testEcho(){
               JSInterface.doEchoTest('This does not get printed in Android Log');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sedicii.app.sedicii.BorrameActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mybrowserAuthorise"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="442dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The WebView seems to be loading correctly (I can see the HELLO from loginProtocol.html on the Android screen).

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION**
I have to wait until the HTML page is loaded. Thanks @KosWarm

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho()");
    }
});
```

Comment: Btw., I have also tried with `window.JSInterface.doEchoTest('This does not get printed in Android Log');` and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to give parameter to your loadUrl method:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

and your javascript function must look like:

```
function testEcho(testHello){
 window.JSInterface.doEchoTest(testHello);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You execute the method `loadUrl` twice
At the second execution, the first page is closed, so its script can not be executed

The following page code works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="visibility:visible">
<!--    Used for debugging -->
<h1>HELLO</h1>

<script>
        function testEcho(){
               JSInterface.doEchoTest('This does not get printed in Android Log');
        }
        testEcho() //added this line
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Update

from this place [Calling Javascript method from within webview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906557/calling-javascript-method-from-within-webview-in-android)

rewrite Activity onCrete method as

```
        myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowserAuthorise);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "JSInterface");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loginProtocol.html");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho()");
        }
        });
```

Comment: Yes,  `testEcho()` is executed now. But with this approach it **always** gets executed when the HTML page is loaded, also when I remove it's call from the Android Java code `webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho()");`. 

I would like to actually _call_ the JS function from Android, not to load an html that automatically executes the function. Is calling `loadUrl` twice bad?

Comment: Maybe this is what you were looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906557/calling-javascript-method-from-within-webview-in-android

Comment: The ```loadUrl``` method is called asynchronously, so the second call was executed before the page was loaded. Because of what the script was not executed

Comment: OMG @KosWarm, you are right! I need to wait for the html page to be loaded in order to cal the JS function!!! I read so many posts, but not that one, THANKS!!!